# Why does this function returns '' instead of a concatenated string

Tags: powershell, string-concatenation

I have numerous fields to quote or double quote depending on the cases, so I have made a functions to do that.

Namely

```
function Add-SingleQuotes 
{  
    param([string] $input)

    $str_return = "'" + $input + "'" 
    return $str_return
}
```

However the result of this function is `''`, whatever the input I give. Why is it so ?

On the contrary, if I enter manually `"'" + "4" + "'"` the result is indeed `'4'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$input` seems to be a reserved word but I can't find a reference to it that makes sense to me.

1. [$input gotchas](http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/11/26/input-gotchas/) perhaps

Changing it to `$inp` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

`$Input` is indeed reserved and holds the object(s) in the pipeline.
This is how you might use the $Input variable in your script:

```
function Add-SingleQuotes {  
    return "'" + $input + "'"
}

4 | Add-SingleQuotes
```

Which results into `'4'`